# Clickable Font Awesome Icon inside Input

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I currently have a font awesome icon that is positioned over an input field. I would like the icon to be clickable, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have wrapped it in a span, and changed the span curser, but it does not appear to be having any effect.

Here's the code:

```css
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}
.inner-addon .fa {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.left-addon .fa {
  left: 0px;
}
.right-addon .fa {
  right: 0px;
}
.left-addon input {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.right-addon input {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#locationClickableIcon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <span id="locationClickableIcon"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs" id='autolocate'></i></span>
<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Zipcode" value="" />
```

Comment: Click works just fine (https://jsfiddle.net/o2vg3men/1/). What exactly are you wanting to happen when clicked?

Comment: For me the icon is positioned inside of the input box- where it becomes not clickable.

Comment: @JakeOls You are not showing the place where it really fails. How can we help without reproducing the problem?

Comment: Then you must be missing some relevant code from your question. Where are `.inner-addon`, `.left-addon`, `.right-addon` ?

Answer (score 0):

It does not have any effect because you haven't asked it to do anything on clicking. That works as per what you wanted. If you want it to behave like a link, change the `<span>` to `<a>` and give a click handler.

**Click Handler**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#locationClickableIcon").click(function () {
    alert("You clicked me!");
  });
});
```

```css
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}

.inner-addon .fa {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.left-addon .fa  { left:  0px;}
.right-addon .fa { right: 0px;}

.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
.right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
#locationClickableIcon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span id="locationClickableIcon"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs" id='autolocate'></i></span>
<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Zipcode" value="" />
```

**Link**

```css
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}

.inner-addon .fa {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.left-addon .fa  { left:  0px;}
.right-addon .fa { right: 0px;}

.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
.right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
#locationClickableIcon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a id="locationClickableIcon" href="http://example.com/"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs" id='autolocate'></i></a>
<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Zipcode" value="" />
```

Comment: Thank you- I added the click handler, but it's still not clickable/the pointer doesn't change. When I change the CSS to move the icon out of the input, it works, just not when it's positioned over the input.

Comment: @JakeOls It works fine for me. Check the snippet. What is the exact problem? Or is that I am unable to understand your issue?

Comment: The snippet you posted has the icon outside of the input box, but my icon is inside of the box.

Comment: @JakeOls So can you build an [mcve] and show the issue?